# how to define a range on x axis in ggplot2 using two columns of a data table

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following data table

```
    name        rating  min_date    max_date    weight
1   abc123      39     2018-04-29   2018-04-29  2000
2   abc123      80     2018-04-16   2018-07-31  3131
```

Using this I would like to plot one line for each row using ggplot library keeping min date to max date on x axis and rating on y axis and color of the line will vary according to weight.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what this graph would look like...there seems to be just one y value so I'm not sure how to make a line with that. Can you clarify or show a handdrawn example? From there it should be easy to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed data as there was the same `min_date` and `max_date` in first row and there were only two observations.

```
data <- read.table(text = "name        rating  min_date    max_date    weight
1   abc123      39     2018-04-29   2018-06-29  2000
2   abc123      80     2018-04-16   2018-07-31  3131
3   abc123      56     2018-04-15   2018-05-30  1831", header = T)
```

One option is to take `weight` as a continuous variable in plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = min_date, xend = max_date, 
                 y = rating, yend = rating, 
                 col = weight)) + 
  geom_segment()
```

[image]

Second option is to take is as a factor:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = min_date, xend = max_date, 
                 y = rating, yend = rating, 
                 col = as.factor(weight))) + 
  geom_segment()
```

[image]